# UIView in a custom xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I created a UIView in a separate subclass of UIView and with an xib.

I have a UIViewController with a UIView in storyboard and I want to set custom UIView to this UIView.

I modified class name in storyboard UIView to the class name of custom UIView. I am getting the UIView on the result but with the frame size of custom UIView. I added correct constraints in the custom xib. and some touch gestures not working as desired because of the wrong frame etc.

Please suggest me if anything wrong I did.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        // Load the UIView from Interface Builder
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TMPhotoEdit" owner:self options:nil];

        // Add UIView to current UIView object.
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }

    return self;
}
```

self.view is the same view object I created a variable for it.

I want the frame to set as same as the one i am using in storyboard.

Solution to get it work using code also helps me a lot. I mean, without IBOutlet in storyboard, just adding this UIView with some frame set to it.

If I call initWithFrame, I can't set the xib like what I am doing with initWithCoder above and initWithCoder is not being called if I use initWithFrame in code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an instance of the view you want to resemble in size

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(otherView.frame.x, otherView.frame.y, otherView.frame.width, otherView.frame.height);
```

Comment: I have self.view which I don't have use with it in the current scenario. viewOne which is added subview to self.view. and a customView in xib. I want viewOne to look exact like customView with constraints added, but in the frame of viewOne.

Comment: In that case, you might need to programmatically copy all the constraints from the target view to the destination view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are doing is not correct but anyway you should load the custom view nib like this

```
self.view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TMPhotoEdit" owner:self options:nil][0];
```

Again this is not correct, why do you need it anyway? but it shall solve your nib loading issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. That is actually what I am doing. I am not fixed for this way. Any other possible way which you can suggest is very helpful. I have a work around. But, I posted this just to find a easy way to directly link the XIB to Storyboard UIView without coding and giving the frame in code.